# How to separate methods from a java class

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I am trying to do the following:

I have a main java class that has multiple methods. Some of these methods call other methods in the same class. For example

```
SendFile(){
....
Save File();
...
}

SaveFile(){
....
}
SendImage(){...}
```

Now, what I want to do is to create a new classes for each method (e.g. SendFile and SendImage) to separate the difenition of each method in a separate class.
However, as we see in the previous example, some methods depends on other methods in the main class (e.g. SendFile needs the savefile methods), however, i do not want to move the savefile definition from the main class. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell for sure based on what you've posted, but one possible solution is to pass an instance of whatever class contains `saveFile` to your `SendFile` (and then [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) to the instance that was passed in). Something like,

```
class Example {
    public void saveFile() {
         System.out.println("Do Save");
    }
}

class SendFile {
    Example e;
    public SendFile(Example e) {
        this.e = e;
    }
    public void sendFile() {
        // ...
        e.saveFile();
    }
}
```